# Is there any problem with fiware repositories?

Tags: fiware, fiware-cygnus

Good morning!

I have tried to install cygnus on fiware lab instances and Amazon EC2 instances but I get an error that the repositories dosen´t exist.
I atached image with the problem, what´s happening?

Thank you for your response!

[image]

**EDIT ANSWER**

I have tried edit the file fiware.repo with the following content https://nexus.lab.fiware.org/repository/raw/public/repositories/el/7/x86_64/fiware-release.repo , but when I tried to install I get an error again.
Whtat's happening?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it was a problem with the public repository. Please, try again.

Comment: Thanks you Dmitrii for your response, but I try again but I get the same error, what´s happening?
Thanks!

Comment: Hi! There is a [PR](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/pull/1525) to cygnus repo, URL changed.